# How to disable KDE Windows preview?

Tags: windows, kubuntu, display

I just turned to Kubuntu straight from Windows so even basic stuff here is a little difficult for me.

When I point my mouse at any task in a panel, an annoying window comes up and I want to turn it off somehow. Please tell me how can I do that.
I'm using the latest Kubuntu 15.10 I think. Thanks

[image: Heres what I'm talking about]

Comment: That also happens in Windows 10, the latest (and the last) version of Windows.

Answer (score 13):

**Right** click on the panel **(Not running application)** -> Task Manager Settings -> General -> **uncheck** "Show Tooltips"

Comment: You're welcome ;) And don't forget to apply changes!

Comment: I want to enable "Show Tooltips" however this checkbox does not work for me - always disabled. How to enable? Bug?

Answer (score 7):

To disable KDE Windows preview : right click your taskbar and select **Task Manager Settings**. In **General** tab, uncheck **Show tooltips**  and save with <kbd>Ok</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to applications->panel->global and find **tooltips_enabled** to uncheck it to   disable permanently.

or

Refer the url for the issue:
http://ubuntuguide.net/disable-tooltips-mouse-over-ubuntu-12-04